# Python seed with a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, random, seed

I have seen that sometimes list is given to `numpy.random.seed(list)`, please explain what happens when list is passed?
What is the advantage of list vs. just an integer?

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) all it says is that it's a legacy function so it shouldn't be used which is not very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume it's because historically NumPy used a Mersenne Twister RNG.
Allowing the seed to be an [array/list](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/31e232c47e6be5ddc1c2433ccb97cec1640df012/numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx#L183) allowed the state (i.e. the 624 32-bit ints) to be explicitly specified while seeding.

The newer RNG interface abstracts out the underlying RNG bit-generator (while also being significantly faster in the cases I've tested) and hence [seeding has been abstracted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/generated/numpy.random.SeedSequence.html) as well.